# Can't use an array in Swift Mailer function

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm using Swift Mailer to send emails to users. I've following script to send email to a number of users at a time.

```
$j=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email))
{
    $message[$j]->addTo($row['email_invited']);
    $mailer->send($message[$j]);
    $j++;
}
```

I get the following error while doing this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Swift_Message as array in
/home/public_html/example.com/people.php on line 21
```

If I try to send emails like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email))
{
    $message->addTo($row['email_invited']);
}
$mailer->send($message);
```

It sends the email normally & every user gets it but the issue with that is every user can see what other users have got the email along with him. So basically in "To" field, every email is bound & thus every users gets to see all other email addresses.
What I want to achieve is every user should get a personalized email only even though it's sent in bulk. That is why I tried to use array & separate email but getting error in that.
Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing. I think you need to create new instance of message (and maybe mailer too) in every loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email))
{
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transportName);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject);
    $message->addTo($row['email_invited']);
    $mailer->send($message);
}
```

Comment: Nope, still getting all the emails.

Comment: I tell you what actually is happening here, if I have 5 emails in DB, it sends five emails to first user, four to second & so on.

Comment: And in those five emails sent to first user, first email contains only his address, second email contains address of him & second user and so on.

Comment: Shanil Soni is correct. Maybe :D See my answer. That should fix if its behavior is caused by this.

Comment: I missed it, it was just creating a new instance, thanks bdw, it worked fine :D

Comment: Hey, I need your help in something else as well, can you please look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652703/using-while-loop-to-fetch-details-in-swift-mailer