# Using while loop to fetch details in Swift Mailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

In my code, I want to include while loop to fetch info from DB & send it in a table form to user.
I tried to search numerous articles but no solutions worked for me actually.
Here's my code:

```
$message->setBody('
<html>
<body>
<table style="margin-top:10px; width: 680px; border:0px;">
<tr>
    <th width="80%">Product Details</th>
    <th width="20%">Amount</th>
</tr>'); /* This is Line 43 */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results2)){
$message->setBody .= ('<tr>
    <th width="80%">'.$row["product_name"].'&nbsp-&nbsp'.
                      $row["quantity"].'&nbsp'.$row["type"].'</th>
    <th width="20%">&#8377;&nbsp;'.$row["subtotal"].'</th>
</tr>');
}
$message->setBody .= ('</table>
</body>
</html>',
'text/html');
```

Error that is coming with this is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/public_html/example.com/
test.php on line 43
```

I know I must be missing something basic but not able to find out. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Results are coming fine from while loop (tested outside email), so that can not be the issue.

**ERROR IN LAST PART**

```
$message->setBody .= ("</table>
</body>
</html>",
'text/html');
```

Error is " 'Unexpected ',' in file at line no. 62 ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have some syntax errors in your code. One place you are calling $message->setBody as function and one place you use it as object property. Secondly, if have below working version for you. Last, in future - read more carefully you code and try to understand what are you doing during developing. Your code has parts that doesn't make any sense.

```
<?php 

$html = "
    <html>
        <body>
            <table style='margin-top:10px; width: 680px; border:0px;'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width='80%'>Product Details</th>
                        <th width='20%'>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results2)) {
    $html .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td width='80%'>{$row["product_name"]}&nbsp-&nbsp{$row["quantity"]}&nbsp{$row["type"]}</td>
                        <td width='20%'>&#8377;&nbsp;{$row["subtotal"]}</td>
                    </tr>";
}
$html .= "
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>";
$message->setBody($html, "text/html");

?>
```

Comment: Problem in last part, $message->setBody .= ("</html>",'text/html'); Unexpected ',' in file.